# django forms print select values

Tags: python, django

I am trying to return the selected choice value from a dropdown menu in `django`. The `option` (in html) is dynamically populated from the database's model primary key.

**HTML**

```
<form class="student-ID-search" action="{% url 'new_coach_schedule' %}" method="post" >
<select class="form-control" id="student_select">
    <option>Select student ID</option>
        {% for student_data in students_data %}
            <option value="{{ student_data.pk }}">{{ student_data.pk }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
</select>
</form>

<button class="btn" type="submit" name="search_result" value="select>
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</button>
```

**views.py**

```
students_data = Student.objects.all()
search_result = NewStudentSearchForm(request.POST)
if 'search_result' in request.POST:
    test_print_to_screen = search_result['student_select']
    print(test_print_to_screen)
    args = {'students_data': students_data}
    return render(request, 'static/html/new_coach_schedule.html', args)
else:
    return render(request, 'static/html/new_coach_schedule.html', args)
```

**forms.py**

```
class NewStudentSearchForm(forms.Form):
    search_field = forms.CharField(max_length=50)  # This is for something else.
    student_select = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Student.objects.all(), empty_label=None)
```

When I make use of `ModelChoiceField`, `test_print_to_screen` does not print out the `selected choice` that I chose in the html select box.. It prints out everything instead.

EG:

```
<select name="student_select" id="id_student_select">
    <option value="5">Student object (5)</option>
    <option value="6">Student object (6)</option>
    <option value="7">Student object (7)</option>
    <option value="8">Student object (8)</option>
    <option value="9">Student object (9)</option>
    <option value="10">Student object (10)</option>
    <option value="11">Student object (11)</option>
    <option value="12">Student object (12)</option>
    <option value="13">Student object (13)</option>
</select>
```

How can I go about in my `forms.py` so that when i select the value in my browser, it will return / print out the selected choice back to me?

---

**Update**

As per the comments, I updated my `views.py` file to include `cleaned_data` as follows:

```
if 'search_result' in request.POST:
    search_result = NewCoachSearchForm(request.POST)

    print(search_result)
    if search_result.is_valid():
        test = search_result.cleaned_data['student_select']
        print(test)
    else:
        print(search_result.errors)
```

However, this produces a `stacktrace error`:

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>student_select<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

Comment: You should check `search_result.is_valid()`, and then you can access the value with `search_result.cleaned_data['student_select']`.

Comment: I just tried that. and it seems to be returning a `key error`. hmm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Django [forms](https://kite.com/python/docs/django.forms), please call form's [`is_valid()`](https://kite.com/python/docs/django.forms.forms.Form.is_valid) method and then if it is valid use `cleaned_data` attribute to access submitted values.

```
students_data = Student.objects.all()
search_result = NewStudentSearchForm(request.POST)
if search_result.is_valid():
    cd = search_result.cleaned_data
    selected_student = cd['student_select']  # Here you get Student instance
```

Comment: My code seems to be giving me a `KeyError`, and I think it seems like the selected choices from the browser is not getting registered. What can i do from here?

Comment: Show the stacktrace.
If is_valid() is true then selected_student must be present in cleaned_data

Comment: I've updated my question to include the stacktrace error. Could you please help to take a look?

Comment: I see in your template `<select class="form-control" id="student_select">`. You will need to add name="student_select" attribute also

Comment: It prints `Student object (10)` because you haven't defined `__str__()` method for Student model. So it prints `<modelname> object (<id>)`.
`selected_student` is already a student instance and you can print `selected_student.<fieldname>` already

Comment: Yes, thanks for making this clear to me too. I was playing around with it and manage to get this as well. :)